# Does Debezium provide delivery and ordering guarantees?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am planning to use [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) for producing events to `Kafka` and I need strong delivery and ordering guarantees. By using `enable.idempotence=true` paramater in producer config I can have these guarantees.

My questions are:

1. How can I achieve this with debezium?
2. Is these guarantees provided by default?
3. Is it configurable? How?

Note: I am planning to use [Debezium Connector for PostgreSQL](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Delevery Sematincs***

[debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) guarantees **at-least-once** delivery:

> When all systems are running nominally or when some or all of the systems are gracefully shut down, then consuming applications can expect to see every event **exactly one time**. However, when things go wrong it is always possible for consuming applications to see events **at least once**.

*Source: **[Why must consuming applications expect duplicate events?](https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#why_must_consuming_applications_expect_duplicate_events)***

---

***Ordering Guarantees***

[debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) has *strong* ordering guarantees:

> Most connectors will record all events for a single database table to a single topic. Additionally, all events within a topic are *totally-ordered*, meaning that the order of all of those events will be maintained. (Even if events are duplicated during failures, the end result after applying all of the events will remain the same.)

*Source: **[How are events for a database organized?](https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_are_events_for_a_database_organized)***

Comment: Maybe,  all events within a topic are totally-ordered within a single partition, so no total order across different partitions of the same topic, and thus if a consumer group is reading concurrently from diffrent partitions, the consumption order as comapred to the database log might not be maintained? am I correct/missing something?

Comment: exactly once, mean that no mater what it will never produce duplicate events.
It's not the case , so Debezium is at least once

Comment: @MazenEzzeddine You are absolutely right there. If we are using multiple partitions then the order is only guaranteed on per partition basis. To ensure that all the inserts, updates, and deletes for an entity go to the same Kafka partition one can use the `message.key.columns` setting in Debezium. Refer more -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932211/does-debezium-use-postgres-primary-key-for-partition-key