# Does Debezium use Postgres primary key for partition key?

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I was looking at Debezium documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/topic-routing.html

I can only see how to specify custom keys, but I cannot understand if by default it is using the DB primary key as routing key.

The DB primary key could even be a triplet like (column1, column2. column3)

Comment: From the docs you linked: "A Debezium change event key uses the table columns that make up the table’s primary key."

Comment: Does that mean that it uses the "primary key columns" to compose the partition key? I didn't find saying it explicitly which raised concerns

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _partition_ key. Googling `"partition key" site:debezium.io` yields only references to non-postgres components. The _change event_ key will be the row's values for the table's primary key columns.

Comment: Sorry I meant kafka partition key. My goal is that all Postgres changes related to a specific primary key (column1, column2. column3) will all go to the same Kafka Partition Key so they can be processed by a unique processor.
I would assume event key and partition key are the same (in Debezium terminology and Kafka terminology)

Comment: for anyone else coming to this, i think this comment here explains it, by default the partition key is hashed from the message key
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68104275/32333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `message.key.columns`

Sample:

```
{
  "name": "my-connector",
  "config": {
    "...": "...",
    "message.key.columns": "my_database.users:department_id"
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-message-key-columns.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? There's no information that this message key is used as the partition key. Am I missing something?

Comment: please read the debezium document :-p